# Loop through multiple panda dataframes to get multiple dataframe output in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have 1000 dataframes that were read by looping 1000 csv files in a directory and my codes are as follows:

```
for csv in csvs:
        df = pd.read_csv(csvs)
        dfs.append(df)
```

So basically I have `dfs[0]` to `dfs[999]`. Then I made a function called `fun` to apply to all of these dataframes. If it were only a few dataframes to go through, I would just do `output = fun(dfs[0])` , `output2 = fun(dfs[1])`, and so on, but since I have so many dataframes, I want to somehow loop them so I can get 1000 separate output for 1000 separate dataframes. Is this feasible? Also, is there a way to export all these output dataframes into csv files at once? I have never dealt with so many dataframes at once before and would really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like you are reading the csvs with a loop like

```
results = []
for df in dfs:
    results.append(fun(df))
```

Or you could do it with a list comprehension like

```
results = [fun(df) for df in dfs]
```

As for writing out the dataframes to csvs it won't technically be "at once". It will be one file at a time, but yes, you can iterate through them with a loop similar to how you are reading them like this.

```
for df, filename in zip(dfs, filenames):
    df.to_csv(filename)
```

Where `filenames` is a list of 1000 filenames corresponding to the csv file name that you want to write the dataframe out to.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a range if I want to loop through dfs[0] to dfs[996] only, instead of every single dataframe?

Comment: Yes, you can do that just with list slicing. So in that case you would do `dfs[:997]` to get dfs[0] to dfs[996] including dfs[996]. Or `dfs[5:10]` to get dfs[5] to dfs[9]. So in the for-loop it looks like: `for df in dfs[:997]:`